# Send and receive multiple request and response (multithreaded) on single socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, spring-integration, connection-pooling

I am having a single socket and multiple thread is accessing it sending request and receiving response.

How to achieve this?
Is it possible?

Comment: What would happen if thread A sends a request, thread B sends a request, then a response arrives. Which thread is that response for?

Comment: @f1sh correct that is the question, how to handle this?

Comment: This question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137948/connection-pooling-and-multithreading-for-tcp-socket

Please look at the above for the answer

Answer (score 1):

TCP has no built-in support for request/reply correlation so Spring Integration only allows one outstanding request on any socket at a time. You can use a `CachingClientConnectionFactory` to use a pool of connections to enable a certain amount of multi-threading.

Comment: That is correct that each socket can only process serially. The thread that reads from the socket waits for, and sends, the response before reading again.
Does Spring Integration resolve this ? With Spring Integration can I send multiple request and receive response asynchronously with single socket?

Comment: NO; read my answer; it uses a semaphore to prevent multiple threads from using the same socket concurrently - not only can threads get the wrong response, the individual packets of each response might even be interspersed - it's very difficult to do what you want unless you have a very controlled environment. The framework cannot make any assumptions about that. When multiplexing on a single socket you need some correlation data in the message themselves. You can, however, use collaborating channel adapters as long as you can do the correlation.

Comment: See [this sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex) for one way to do that.

Comment: I found out apache Camel, seems it is possible with this. 
http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html